Hyper-V and ESXi VLAN Tagging not working properly with AOS on CX6000
I am struggling to get a VLAN setup working in our physical test rack.
It should actually be a very simple setup -no routing, just a single switch with VLANs to separate networks.
The switch is an Aruba CX 6000, and I have configured the following VLANs:

1 - native - General Uplink into our internal company network (DHCP network)
300 - Custom1 - A VLAN for system-under-test devices (DHCP network)
500 - Custom2 - A VLAN for devices outside the test network (static network)

The switch has 2 ports connected to an ESXi host for virtualization in a link-aggregation, using IP-based-hashing.
This LAG is configured to have a native VLAN of 1 and an allowed list of all:
    vlan trunk native 1
    vlan trunk allowed all

I have configured the same settings on a singular debug interface port connected to my laptop.
My laptop is running Hyper-V, and I've created additional ManagementOS adapters on the Hyper-V virtual switch.
The network that seems to be always working is the native one, since it comes in untagged.
However, for any VLAN that I attempt to tag, either via ESXi or via Hyper-V, I cannot establish communication with that network.
I can actually see traffic FROM the network when opened in Wireshark, but "nothing seems to properly leave my adapter".
So, in the mode where the VLAN is tagged, using a vSwitch + Portgroup on ESXi or with a VMNetworkAdapter on Hyper-V, I connect establish ping or DHCP requests for VLAN 300 and 500 running as a tagged trunk.
However, once I switch those ports to access mode, meaning only a single VLAN is present, the communication works fine.
So, I am at a loss as to why my communication gets broken every time I try to communicate to the switch using tagged packets, whenever it is configured as such in the hypervisors.
Does anyone have an idea on why that occurs?
Here are things I've tried:

Configure Aruba CX 6000 Debug interface as trunk with all allowed VLANs, and a native VLAN 1:

Despite being unable to successfully transmit my pings to the target, I can open Wireshark and see traffic of the VLAN and also from the target.
> Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -SwitchName "vSwitch_Ext_SlimAdapter" -Name "vEth_EXT_Slim_MMC_System" | Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -Access -VlanId 500
> ping 172.168.1.200

Pinging 172.168.1.200 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.168.1.142: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 172.168.1.142: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 172.168.1.142: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 172.168.1.142: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 172.168.1.200:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)


Configure Aruba CX 6000 Debug interface as an access port for VLAN 500

> Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -SwitchName "vSwitch_Ext_SlimAdapter" -Name "vEth_EXT_Slim_MMC_System" | Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -Untagged
> ping 172.168.1.200

Pinging 172.168.1.200 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.168.1.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=100
Reply from 172.168.1.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=100
Reply from 172.168.1.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=100
Reply from 172.168.1.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=100

A similar behavior happens inside the VM in ESXi, where I select the VLAN via Portgroups.
There, only the provided native VLAN by the Switch is working, whereas for all other VLANs, the VM can only see traffic but not actually communicate.
Is this a problem with Aruba CX 6000 or the firmware running on it?
The Aruba CX 6000 is running PL.10.14.1000, which is the latest available image for that switch.

EDIT:
To clarify what I mean with "nothing seems to properly leave my adapter": When my laptop and the VM are both connected to one of the tagged VLANs, then they can see the traffic of devices connected through access ports on that VLAN via Wireshark. However, any packets sent are only seen by themselves, but not the other device, meaning they don't actually get into the network.
This is however not the case for the native VLAN (i.e. untagged).
But in theory, both ESXi and Hyper-V should be able to properly handle the tagging of packets when configured as such, so my assumption here is that the switch is actually not doing what it is supposed to do.
